# Visualizar imagen en viewer de windows con VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, .net

Quiero visualizar una imagen guardada en sqlserver como tipo image en el visor de windows, pero el problema que tengo es como obtengo el nombre del archivo para pasarselo a la propiedad FileName mi imagen la obtengo de la siguiente forma y no hay problema de la visualizacion en el pictureBox

```html
            Dim by(reader.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, 0) - 1) As Byte
                    reader.GetBytes(0, 0, by, 0, by.Length)
                    Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(by)
                    pbImagen.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                    reader.Close()
```

Pero no se como obtener el nombre de esa imagen para enviarlo al proceso que abre el viewer de windows apartir del codigo de arriba

```html
    Dim photoViewer As New Process()
    photoViewer.StartInfo.FileName = nombreImagen
    photoViewer.StartInfo.Arguments = "Your image file path"
    photoViewer.Start()
```

Comment: creo que tienes que guardar el archivo primero, en una ubicación física y es lo que le tienes que pasar, ya tienes el memorystream, solo es guardar eso en un archivo y pasar la ruta en "Your image file path".

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea y sabrás como lo puedo guardar?

Comment: http://net-informations.com/q/faq/memory.html

Answer (score 0):

¿Has intentado guardar la imagen en una carpeta temporal y abrir-la desde allí?

Es decir, puedes hacer lo siguiente para tener una dirección valida...

```
Dim by(reader.GetBytes(0, 0, Nothing, 0, 0) - 1) As Byte
reader.GetBytes(0, 0, by, 0, by.Length)
Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(by)
pbImagen.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
reader.Close()

Dim TemporalFileName As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) & "\TempoFileName.bmp"
pbImagen.Image.Save(TemporalFileName)

Dim photoViewer As New Process()
photoViewer.StartInfo.FileName = TemporalFileName
photoViewer.StartInfo.Arguments = "Your image file path"
photoViewer.Start()
```